# SpringMVC: ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource Encoding configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I have a problem reading some character in a property file in Spring MVC like (é,ê,...)

In my AppConfig. I added this to configure ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource:

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

When I get the message using MessageSource.

```
messages.getMessage("KEY",null,"Default", new Locale("fr"));
```

I still get Character like "?" instead of "é".

Can someOne please guides me how to display the right character ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .properties file in notepad++ or other editor to verify your file has UTF-8 encoding. If not, save it to UTF-8.